# Bitrix 24 CMS NEWS $arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL]

Tags: битрикс

есть код, писал не я, но мне надо исправить.
На главное страницу есть компонент который выводит 3 последние новости, а если нажать на любую новость, то он открывает ссылкой значение
<a href=""
Мне надо поменять DETAIL_PAGE_URL (так как у новостей поменялся URL и этот компонент перестал работать)
Подскажите, пожалуйста куда в б24 лезть что бы поменять его

Компонент, начало

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<div class="container" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
    <h2>НОВОСТИ</h2>
    <div class="row">
    <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?>
        <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><br />
    <?endif;?>
    <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
        <?
        $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
        $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
        ?>
        <div class="fullist col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
            <div class="pic-container">
            <? if(is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])){?>
                <a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>"><img
                            class="border-bot"
                            border="0"
                            height="auto"
                            src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
                            alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
                            title="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
                            /></a>
            <? }else{?>
                <a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>"><img class="img-fluid" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/images/ban800x600-cap-news.jpg"/></a>
             <? } ?>
```

Comment: В параметрах компонента есть поле где мы заполняем ссылку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Само значение DETAIL_PAGE_URL берется из БД, а сам его формат в настройках инфоблока в блоке https://tppr.me/2WzeV (скриншот настроек инфоблока). Так же обратите внимание на параметр ЧПУ в настройках компонента.

Answer (score 0):

В параметрах компонента есть поле где мы заполняем ссылку(DETAIL_PAGE_URL)

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите